# ASP.NET Web API Returning empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've just started to learn about ASP.NET Web API and I've created a Person model with a repo that stores a collection of that model type in memory for testing.

When I call my /api/values which break pointing through should return a List however all I get is "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApiExample.Models"/>"
```

Code from values controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
{
    return personRepo.GetPeople();
}
```

Code snippet from PersonRepository:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return context.Person.ToList();
}
```

Developer tools capture from IE of url /api/values, Reponse Body = `[]`
However it works when I specify an int, e.g. /api/values/3

```
{"Id":3,"Name":"Sarah","Age":54,"Gender":"Fenale","IsMarried":true}
```

Any clues?

REPO:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApiExample.Models
{
    public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private PersonContext context;

        public PersonRepository(PersonContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void DeletePerson(int Id)
        {
            Person person = context.Person.Find(Id);
            context.Person.Remove(person);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            return context.Person.ToList();
        }

        public Person GetPersonById(int Id)
        {
            return context.Person.Find(Id);
        }

        public void InsertPerson(Person person)
        {
            context.Person.Add(person);
        }
        public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
        {
            context.Entry(person).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Person Context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApiExample.Models
{
    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Values Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WebApiExample.Models;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApiExample.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        private IPersonRepository personRepo;

        public ValuesController()
        {
            this.personRepo = new PersonRepository(new PersonContext());
            Person person = new Person()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Joanna",
                Age = 28,
                Gender = "Female",
                IsMarried = true
            };
            Person person1 = new Person()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Jenna",
                Age = 52,
                Gender = "Female",
                IsMarried = true
            };
            Person person2 = new Person()
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "John",
                Age = 54,
                Gender = "Male",
                IsMarried = true
            };
            Person person3 = new Person()
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "Jessop",
                Age = 28,
                Gender = "Male",
                IsMarried = true
            };
            Person person4 = new Person()
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "Rachael",
                Age = 24,
                Gender = "Female",
                IsMarried = false
            };
            personRepo.InsertPerson(person);
            personRepo.InsertPerson(person1);
            personRepo.InsertPerson(person2);
            personRepo.InsertPerson(person3);
            personRepo.InsertPerson(person4);
        }

        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
        {
            return personRepo.GetPeople();
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public Person Get(int id)
        {
            return personRepo.GetPersonById(id);
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]Person person)
        {
            personRepo.InsertPerson(person);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Person value)
        {
            Person person = personRepo.GetPersonById(id);
            personRepo.UpdatePerson(person);
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            personRepo.DeletePerson(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApiExample.Models
{
    interface IPersonRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople();
        Person GetPersonById(int Id);
        void InsertPerson(Person person);
        void DeletePerson(int Id);
        void UpdatePerson(Person person);
        void Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a helper variable in `GetPeople() { persons = context.Person.ToList() ...` and inspect it. If it's empty, the problem is in your repository code.

Comment: Make sure the Person class' properties are public. (both the getter and setter need to be public for the XML serialiser)

Comment: Can you post your /api/values/{int} code?

Comment: api/values/id responsed Json? Check whether your API responsed Json or Xml